# How do I read "failed linking file resources" error messages?

Tags: android, android-resources

I get these regularly and spontaneously and I am never able to deliberately solve them. Here is the build log:

```
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:103)

Caused by: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: Android resource linking failed
Output:  X:\Documents\All\Creative\Programming\Projects\Theo\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_login.xml:74: error: resource integer/login (aka org.andrewedgar.theo:integer/login) not found.
error: failed linking file resources.
```

I see a reference to one of my activity layouts (activity_login), but I haven't touched that file or its corresponding class in weeks. There's nothing even on line 74 there:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="org.andrewedgar.theo.LoginActivity">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="286dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textInputLayout"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/logo" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/textInputLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:textColorHint="@color/hintColor"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textInputLayout2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

        <AutoCompleteTextView
            android:id="@+id/login_email"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="@font/nunito"
            android:hint="@string/prompt_email"
            android:imeOptions="actionNext"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textColorHint="@color/hintColor"
            android:textIsSelectable="false" />

    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/textInputLayout2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:textColorHint="@color/hintColor"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/login_sign_in_button"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/login_password"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="@font/nunito"
            android:hint="@string/prompt_password"
            android:imeActionId="@integer/login"
            android:imeActionLabel="@string/action_sign_in_short"
            android:imeOptions="actionUnspecified"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textColorHint="@color/hintColor" />

    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/login_sign_in_button"
        style="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:background="@android:color/background_light"
        android:fontFamily="@font/nunito_bold"
        android:onClick="signInExistingUser"
        android:text="@string/action_sign_in_short"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/login_register_button"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/login_register_button"
        style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:fontFamily="@font/nunito_bold"
        android:onClick="registerNewUser"
        android:text="@string/action_register"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Reverting back to an a version that worked when I committed it didn't solve the problem either. Invalidate Caches/Restart and Clean/Rebuild does not work. Is there a typical solution to this type of error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are referencing an attribute `"@integer/login"` that most probably doesn't exist in your project. 
In fact, the error stated the following:

```
error: resource integer/login (aka org.andrewedgar.theo:integer/login) not found.
```

Generally, this type of errors are related to xml and points that you are using an attribute somewhere that is not recognized.

Comment: Okay I deleted the reference to it and that allowed it to build, but it broke an activity that needed it. No idea where it went.

Answer (score 1):

`error: resource integer/login (aka org.andrewedgar.theo:integer/login) not found`. It looks like you used to have this resource, but now you don’t have it.

You need to remove `@integer/login` and to do `clean` and `build`. If it not help, do:

> File -> Invalidate Caches/Restart

Or you just can add login resources into your xml file in `values` folder.

Comment: Ah yes, I should have mentioned that I have already done this normal stuff to no avail

Comment: You use `@integer/login`. Have you xml file with this value?

Comment: Not that I know of, but it worked before. Where would the file have gone?

Comment: `error: resource integer/login (aka org.andrewedgar.theo:integer/login) not found` It looks like you used to have this resource, but now you don’t have it. `org.andrewedgar.theo` is your package or some lib?

Comment: My package. I have no idea where it would have gone. I deleted the line that had that on it but it's still looking for it.

Comment: After removal need clean project. Because you have generated resources with link on `@integer/login`

Answer (score 1):

> **resource** `integer/login` not found.

how about to add the missing resource, of type `integer` with name `login`?

eg. with a `res/values/numerical.xml` alike:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <integer name="login">1</integer>
</resources>
```